# How to run the dialog command with proccess?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, process, dialog

**NOTE:** *Please look at my code, it's a Bash script.*

I want to display both dialogs on the screen at the same time,  one dialog displays this:

```
tail –f from - /var/log/proccess1.log
```

and the second dialog display this:

```
tail –f from the file - /var/log/proccess2.log
```

but the sad fact is that I can display only one dialog and not both dialogs (because when I run the first dialog, the second dialog will activate only if the first dialog is killed).

So I create a process on the second dialog `( ….. ) &`, in order to display both dialogs. But …. the second dialog creates a process number but does not create the second dialog's GUI, (seems that when we create dialog with process, the process does not send the dialog to standard output).

So how do I run the second dialog with a process but send the dialog GUI to the screen, or is there some other solution in order to display both dialogs on screen?

#### My code

```
     #!/bin/bash

     # this dialog will locate the tail box on the top of the screen
     dialog --begin 15 10  --tailbox   /var/log/proccess1.log  13 125 


     # this dialog will locate the tail box down in the screen
     ( dialog --begin 37 10  --tailbox   /var/log/proccess2.log    13 125 ) &
```